# How can you setup git to track two seperate directories

Tags: git

If I have directory A and directory B like,

```
/A
/B
```

How can I get git to cover both? I dont want to combine into one
directory. Because that would require re-writing the app.

Edit: If you have a split structure in a sense, where /A  and /B are on one server and, both are at / level -- from old project. The code based writes to these directories independently. Keeping it simple, /A could be log files, code, data. /B could be code, data,  /C could be old data. Can I setup git to cover both directories---problem is they are at root level and the code/application addresses them separately. I could just use git twice one per directory or combine the directories and rewrite the entire application.

Answer (score 2):

Make both of them subdirectories of a top level folder and make that the root of your repository.

```
/Root
  .git
  .gitignore
  /A
  /B
  /C
```

If you want to ignore anything, just add it to your .gitignore file. In your case, to exclude /C just add this line to your .gitignore file

> /C

Comment: Yes, that is one way. There is alot of code referencing the two dir. This require a complete rewrite of the application.

Comment: also, there is a dir C, which has alot of data that does not need to be in git repo.

Answer (score 1):

You could make A and B be symbolic links pointing to subdirectories of a Git repository somewhere else on the disk, where the actual contents of A and B are.

Comment: I was thinking about creating symslinks, but was not sure about if git would track the link or orginal file?

Comment: @Merlin I was thinking that you would move A and B to a new directory, where you can run `git init` and create a repository. Then you would create symlinks at the original positions of A and B, pointing to where they are in the repository. This would not necessitate Git tracking any links.

Comment: @Klas... App writes to the those directories, logs, etc......I guess I could create two git repo's one for each dir. I thought there might be a more elegant solution or git had functionality for this.